# fractional equation in database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

is there is a way to store and retrive a fractional equation into my database ? im using it in my android application which work with the database through php and im using phpMyAdmin database.

for example this equation:

[image]

is there is a way ??

Comment: first you tell us how you're translating that fancy graphical equation to a textual form for storage, and then we'll just tell you "it's text, store it like you would store any other text".

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean by "E=MC2"

Comment: @MarcB it will be nPr=n!/(n-r)! but i don't want the /

Comment: you don't want division? ok. `n! * ((n-r)! ^ -1)`?

Comment: @MarcB i want the line and some variabls over and under it .. is not possible ?

Comment: no, it's not possible. your equation is a **PICTURE** of an idealized/human-readable equation. The only way you'll store that as-is in a database is either as a literal image blob, or in some encoding format, e.g. MathML. And if it's encoded, it's NOT going to look like the original picture, but that encoding can be converted BACK into that picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML), for example, or any other way of converting any formula to a string of characters. It may be a [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) notation. Then just save the string in your database.

BTW, depending on the language you're using, there should be libraries rendering MathML into graphic equations like in your question.

And if you need to show it on Android device, you can generate HTML/CSS with this [library](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/) for example

Comment: its a web language right ? and do you mean to store code of MathMl of my equation in my database and then converted and display it in my android application ?

Comment: exactly. And not sure what you meant by "web language"? It's an XML-based notation allowing to store formulas. With the help of libraries like MathJAX, you can render a html5 or graphic (jpeg/png) output from MathML. It can be shown then anywhere.